# how can we track the status of email sent from drupal

Tags: php, drupal-6

Hiii
how can we track the status of email sent from drupal. I want to know all the email sent from my site is delivered to client mail or not. I delivered also want to know it is read or not.

Is it posssible. if possible how can we do this...

Comment: Short answer is that you cannot (at least, not more than you can check whether a post-card was delivered). However, you can analyse *returned* e-mails with an e-mail bounce handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to send the email in HTML format and include a small (1px square) transparent gif, served from a PHP script on your server, with the unique id of the email appended as a GET parameter in the gif's URL. Your script can then log which emails have been opened using drupal's watchdog() function or whatever.

This is not foolproof of course, as some people's mail clients automatically refuse to download images (in order to prevent this sort of tracking by spammers) or will open HTML email in plaintext mode e.g. mobile clients. However, this could still be useful to you, depending on your situation.

The [CiviCRM](http://civicrm.org/) Drupal module provides this functionality as it's focused on political campaigning and read tracking is potentially helpful even if it's not perfect, but you'd have to use the CiviMail component to send the messages if you want to use this (it also tracks bounces, so not a bad solution).

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Once it's been handed over to the mailer daemon you have no control over it any more.

There are ways of seeing if the message was received, but none of them are reliable.  You can request a receipt, but the user is under no obligation to send one, and they may by annoyed by the request.  You could embed a web bug (a link to an image that actually runs a script to log the fact the mail was received), but they are easily blocked and you could only use them with HTML mail anyway.